# Is Spanner's DatabaseClient threadsafe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

We are currently retrieving a DatabaseClient for Spanner like so:

```
DatabaseClient dbClient = spanner.getDatabaseClient(...)
```

Is it safe to use this DatabaseClient object across multiple threads?  Specifically, we are wanting to dependency inject an instance of DatabaseClient and want to understand if it is threadsafe and can be reused, or whether each thread should make a call to spanner?

This is being used in a web API service, so lots of incoming requests to URLs, each incoming request requires a spanner connection.  What is the best object to share? We don't want each session to have to, for example, load in the Google JSON credentials (which we assume happens in SpannerOptions Builder).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it should be thread-safe.

`DatabaseClient` is [implemented](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/master/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/DatabaseClientImpl.java) using the `SessionPool` class. The note about thread-safety can be seen in the `SessionPool` [implementation](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/master/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/SessionPool.java).

Comment: Thanks Dan, for reference for anybody else reading -> DatabaseClient/DatabaseClientImpl are 'dumb' wrappers around SessionPool that actually manages and coordinates connection pooling to the DB. So DatabaseClientImpl can be singleton effectively.

Comment: One other question - if sharing DatabaseClient across an App, does it matter that spanner.closeAsync().get(); is never therefore called?

Comment: There is a limit for number of sessions per database[see https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/limits]. Although inactive sessions are eventually garbage collected, we recommend to keep the session pool alive for the lifetime of the application and clean it up once those sessions are no longer needed, e.g. on app shutdown.